# EPL drawing circle from c#?

Tags: c#, epl

Cannot draw a circle in EPL language to print from a label printer. I'm doing a program using c# and it communicates over the network with a label printer, everything works fine, but cannot find a command to draw a circle. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have explanation of how to draw several shapes in C# for printers, some of the features won't work with EPL printers.

http://www.neodynamic.com/Products/Help/ThermalLabel2.0/items_shape.htm